# django template URL tag error

Tags: django, templates, url, django-templates, templatetag

template:

```
            <!-- Images slide as a row starts -->             
            <!-- power.views.IMAGE_SLIDES_ROW returns image_slider_row/   -->
                {% url power.views.IMAGE_SLIDES_ROW %}            
            <!-- Images as a row Ends -->
```

url conf:

```
url(r'^image_slider_row/', views.images_slider_row_func, name='image_slider_row'),
```

View :

```
def images_slider_row(request):     
    print "Debug-1"    
    return render_to_response('images_slider_row.html', {})
```

actually I am expecting "images_slider_row_func" will get call on url tag execution but it is not happening, it is showing following string in the browser

> `/images_slider_row/`

am I missing anything or am I misunderstood the concept? Please help me for fixing this issue.

Comment: Even though {% power.views.IMAGE_SLIDES_ROW %} points to a view, django cannot resolve it unless it is in urls.py, so why no just do a {% url image_slider_row %} ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`{% url ... %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) does not call the url but puts text to make that url either from named url or view path etc.